# Reorder form elements and change labels on django password change form

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm still relatively new to Django and I've managed to set up a password change form using my template. I don't know how to change the order and labels for the elements. I have attached an image showing how the form currently looks, I would like to move the second text box (new password) underneath the explanation text and to change the first and last input labels.

Could you please point me in the right direction?

[image: current view]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't help more without your template code but. From the django Render Fields [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually).

> We don’t have to let Django unpack the form’s fields; we can do it manually if we like (allowing us to reorder the fields, for example). Each field is available as an attribute of the form using {{ form.name_of_field }}, and in a Django template, will be rendered appropriately.

```
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.subject.errors }}
    <label for="{{ form.subject.id_for_label }}">Email subject:</label>
    {{ form.subject }}
</div>
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.message.errors }}
    <label for="{{ form.message.id_for_label }}">Your message:</label>
    {{ form.message }}
</div>
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.sender.errors }}
    <label for="{{ form.sender.id_for_label }}">Your email address:</label>
    {{ form.sender }}
</div>
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.cc_myself.errors }}
    <label for="{{ form.cc_myself.id_for_label }}">CC yourself?</label>
    {{ form.cc_myself }}
</div>
```